# Is there a Java API that can binary communicate with a Microsoft WCF service?

Tags: java, wcf, api, communication

I would like to be able to do binary communication between a WCF server and Java client. Is this possible? Are there any API's that can communicate with this Microsoft protocol?

Answer (score 0):

Is WCF on the server a requirement? If no, then our [MsgConnect](http://www.eldos.com/msgconnect/) product is similar (but simpler and easier to use) to WCF and it's cross-platofrm, from smartphones to desktops to servers, with Java and .NET implementations available. And source code is available as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for [WSIT](http://wsit.java.net/) - Java's bridge to Microsoft WCF (previously known as Project Tango):

> All of Metro (including WSIT) is tested for **interoperability** between the Java platform and Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) (aka Indigo) in .NET 3.0 and .NET 3.5