# Encode/Decode Microsoft binary XML in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, wcf

Is there a simple way to encode/decode Microsoft binary XML in Java? I've found this [WCF related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711671/is-there-a-java-api-that-can-binary-communicate-with-a-microsoft-wcf-service), but I don't need to communicate with the server (and thus I don't need a framework for WCF) but just to encode/decode strings (library function or an algorythm).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no Java implementation of .NET Binary. Try Fast Infoset, it is standards-based and much more compact than .NET Binary. On Java it is freely available, on .NET it is commercially available in [FastInfoset.NET](http://www.noemax.com/products/fastinfoset/index.html).

Comment: Unfortunately we can not modify the server code at our current project so we can't use it. Thanks for the link anyway.